# Pig equivalent of SQL GREATEST / LEAST?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to find the Pig equivalent of [the SQL functions `GREATEST` and `LEAST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST). These functions are the scalar equivalent of the aggregate SQL functions `MAX` and `MIN`, respectively.

Essentially, I want to be able to say something like this:

```
x = LOAD 'file:///a/b/c.csv' USING PigStorage() AS (a: int, b: int, c: int);
y = FOREACH x GENERATE a AS a: int, b AS b: int, c AS c: int, GREATEST(a, b, c) AS g: int;
```

I know I could use bags and `MAX` to get this done, but I'm translating from another language into Pig and that implementation would be difficult to integrate.

Is there an "inline" approach I could use here? Some builtin function I'm overlooking, or maybe a UDF in Piggybank or DataFu, for example, would be ideal! If there's a completely "inline" version that uses bags and I'm just not thinking of it, that's fine too!

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that there are "inline" bag-based approaches that work:

```
x = LOAD 'file:///a/b/c.csv' USING PigStorage() AS (a: int, b: int, c: int);
y = FOREACH x GENERATE a AS a: int, b AS b: int, c AS c: int, MAX(TOBAG(a, b, c)) AS g: int;
```

Comment: glad it was useful! :)