# Max for multiple columns in pig join

Tags: apache-pig

I have 2 data files to load in pig .

```
A = LOAD 'temp.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (user:chararray,day:chararray,joinKey:chararray);
B = LOAD 'new.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (user:chararray,day:chararray,joinKey:chararray);
c = join A by (joinKey),B by (joinKey);
d = FOREACH c GENERATE MAX(A:day,B:day) as maxDay
```

This is not working as there is no group by.
How to achieve the maximum for the 2 columns.
After getting the max i need to store the user related to the max day field.

Comment: got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262945/pig-equivalent-of-sql-greatest-least
For the second problem i need to use case.

Comment: What output would you like to achieve? If you are only interested in max date you can UNION both datasets and then use group by.