# Max of values in a bag

Tags: apache-pig

Follow up question to [Pig equivalent of SQL GREATEST / LEAST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262945/pig-equivalent-of-sql-greatest-least)

I did

`x = LOAD 'file:///a/b/c.csv' USING PigStorage() AS (a: int, b: int, c: int);
y = FOREACH x GENERATE a AS a: int, b AS b: int, c AS c: int, MAX(TOBAG(a, b, c)) AS g: int;`

as described, which gets me the max value (Awesome btw!).  How could you tell which column the value was originally in (a, b or c)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple method can be:

```
z = FOREACH y GENERATE
      a,
      b,
      c,
      g,
      CASE WHEN
         g==a THEN 'a'
         g==b THEN 'b'
         g==c THEN 'c'
      END as 'which_column';
```